# Starting a spidev program during U-boot or right after U-boot

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, spi, u-boot, device-tree

So I need some guidance on how to make spidev run at the very beginning of the kernel init. I am using an ILI9341 display connected to the pocketbeagle that is being driven using SPI. Thing is, I need to "send" an image to the display during boot. For that, I need to start spidev at the very beginning of the boot process, and I am not really sure what process starts spidev. I am not sure if it's something started by a systemd process or elsewhere.

Here is my device tree declaration of spidev (original: [am335x-pocketbeagle.dts](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.14/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-pocketbeagle.dts)):

```
&spi0 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    status = "okay";

    channel@0 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        compatible = "spidev";
        reg = <0>;
        spi-max-frequency = <100000000>;
    };

    channel@1 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        compatible = "spidev";
        reg = <1>;
        spi-max-frequency = <100000000>;
        status = "disabled";
    };
};

&spi1 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    status = "okay";

    channel@0 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        compatible = "spidev";
        reg = <0>;
        spi-max-frequency = <100000000>;
    };

    channel@1 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        compatible = "spidev";
        reg = <1>;
        spi-max-frequency = <100000000>;
    };
};
```

Here is the beginning of the boot process (just the first few secs is shown here):

```
U-Boot SPL 2018.01-dirty (May 06 2018 - 17:12:35)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2018.01-dirty (May 06 2018 - 17:12:35 -0400)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Using default environment

Model: BeagleBoard.org PocketBeagle
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
board_name=[A335PBGL] ...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
** Bad device 0:2 0x82000000 **
** Bad device 0:2 0x82000000 **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
24 bytes read in 15 ms (1000 Bytes/s)
Loaded environment from /boot/uEnv.txt
Checking if uname_r is set in /boot/uEnv.txt...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1
Running uname_boot ...
loading /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.113-ti-r149 ...
9431560 bytes read in 612 ms (14.7 MiB/s)
loading /boot/dtbs/4.4.113-ti-r149/am335x-pocketbeagle.dtb ...
130113 bytes read in 84 ms (1.5 MiB/s)
uboot_overlays: add [enable_uboot_overlays=1] to /boot/uEnv.txt to enable...
debug: [console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait]                                                                                                                                                              ...
debug: [bootz 0x82000000 - 0x88000000] ...
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8ffdd000, end 8ffffc40 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.113-ti-r149 (luis@luis) (gcc version 5.5.0 (Lin                                                                                                                                                             aro GCC 5.5-2017.10) ) #2 SMP Fri Jun 29 16:50:45 EDT 2018
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instructio                                                                                                                                                             n cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: TI AM335x PocketBeagle
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 48 MiB at 0x9c800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon )
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @df8f2000 s24192 r8192 d20864 u5324                                                                                                                                                             8
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pag                                                                                                                                                             es: 129408
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 r                                                                                                                                                             o rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 448072K/522240K available (12533K kernel code, 1016K rwda                                                                                                                                                             ta, 4064K rodata, 824K init, 857K bss, 25016K reserved, 49152K cma-reserved, 0K                                                                                                                                                              highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 496 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc103d760   (16598 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc103e000 - 0xc110c000   ( 824 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc110c000 - 0xc120a0e8   (1017 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc120d000 - 0xc12e355c   ( 858 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=2 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=32, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0xfa200000 (revision 5.0) with 128 interrup                                                                                                                                                             ts
[    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: timer2 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000022] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478                                                                                                                                                             484971ns
[    0.000048] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max                                                                                                                                                             _idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000061] OMAP clocksource: timer1 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.001914] clocksource_probe: no matching clocksources found
[    0.002223] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.002254] WARNING: Your 'console=ttyO0' has been replaced by 'ttyS0'
[    0.002262] This ensures that you still see kernel messages. Please
[    0.002268] update your kernel commandline.
[    0.002289] Calibrating delay loop... 995.32 BogoMIPS (lpj=1990656)
[    0.021215] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.021365] Security Framework initialized
[    0.021380] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.021418] AppArmor: AppArmor disabled by boot time parameter
[    0.021590] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.021603] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.022464] Initializing cgroup subsys io
[    0.022497] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.022543] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.022561] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.022578] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.022592] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.022607] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    0.022630] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
[    0.022688] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.022747] ftrace: allocating 37522 entries in 111 pages
[    0.128715] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket -1, mpidr 0
[    0.128838] Setting up static identity map for 0x80008280 - 0x800082e0
[    0.133343] Brought up 1 CPUs
[    0.133369] SMP: Total of 1 processors activated (995.32 BogoMIPS).
[    0.133377] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.134975] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.172782] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c                                                                                                                                                              rev 3
[    0.223366] omap_hwmod: debugss: _wait_target_disable failed
[    0.277491] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, ma                                                                                                                                                             x_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.277527] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.281782] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    0.321202]    arm4regs  :  1219.000 MB/sec
[    0.361191]    8regs     :   957.000 MB/sec
[    0.401188]    32regs    :  1089.000 MB/sec
[    0.441187]    neon      :  1725.000 MB/sec
[    0.441195] xor: using function: neon (1725.000 MB/sec)
[    0.441228] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.442711] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.445513] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.446456] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.446477] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.452463] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    0.475562] No ATAGs?
[    0.475601] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    0.476766] omap4_sram_init:Unable to allocate sram needed to handle errata I                                                                                                                                                             688
[    0.476789] omap4_sram_init:Unable to get sram pool needed to handle errata I                                                                                                                                                             688
[    0.557214] raid6: neonx2   gen()  1887 MB/s
[    0.625198] raid6: neonx2   xor()  1161 MB/s
[    0.625207] raid6: using algorithm neonx2 gen() 1887 MB/s
[    0.625214] raid6: .... xor() 1161 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    0.625221] raid6: using intx1 recovery algorithm
[    0.635476] edma 49000000.edma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    0.640859] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.641610] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.642367] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.642449] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.642560] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.643413] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wk                                                                                                                                                             up@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.644286] omap_i2c 4802a000.i2c: bus 1 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    0.644967] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 2 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    0.645404] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.645482] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.645611] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.645620] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giome                                                                                                                                                             tti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.645655] PTP clock support registered
[    0.646615] omap-mailbox 480c8000.mailbox: omap mailbox rev 0x400
[    0.648938] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.648955] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.648961] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.649029] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.649769] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1
[    0.773340] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.774347] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.774397] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.774456] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.774539] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.774560] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.774925] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.775551] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.775567] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.775574] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.775580] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.776750] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counter                                                                                                                                                             s available
[    0.780201] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.780300] audit: type=2000 audit(0.712:1): initialized
[    0.790964] zbud: loaded
[    0.791713] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.791995] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.795073] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.795149] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.795157] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.795187] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.795579] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    0.796227] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enable                                                                                                                                                             d
[    0.805645] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 2                                                                                                                                                             47)
[    0.806079] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.806100] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.806175] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.808070] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
[    0.809173] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=0
[    0.809332] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=1
[    0.809521] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=2
[    0.809670] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=3
[    0.810219] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=4
[    0.810400] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=5
[    0.810547] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=6
[    0.810691] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=7
[    0.810844] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=8
[    0.811050] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=9
[    0.811224] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=10
[    0.811392] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=11
[    0.811539] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=12
[    0.811692] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=13
[    0.811838] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=14
[    0.811988] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=15
[    0.812144] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=16
[    0.812293] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=17
[    0.812445] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=18
[    0.812598] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=19
[    0.812752] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=20
[    0.812907] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=21
[    0.813055] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=22
[    0.813189] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=23
[    0.813332] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=24
[    0.813467] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=25
[    0.813602] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=26
[    0.813842] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=27
[    0.814192] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=28
[    0.814350] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=29
[    0.814491] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=30
[    0.814629] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=31
[    0.814774] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=32
[    0.814911] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=33
[    0.815048] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=34
[    0.815196] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=35
[    0.815338] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=36
[    0.815485] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=37
[    0.815624] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=38
[    0.815762] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=39
[    0.815909] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=40
[    0.816053] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=41
[    0.816194] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=42
[    0.816343] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: Allocated GPIO id=43
[    0.816354] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: ready
[    0.822156] wkup_m3_ipc 44e11324.wkup_m3_ipc: could not get rproc handle
[    0.824170] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 6 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.827881] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 158, base_baud =                                                                                                                                                              3000000) is a 8250
[    1.921701] console [ttyS0] enabled
```

"Important" things like GPIOs and I2C appear to be running at the very beginning of the boot process. How could I do the same thing with spidev?

I am a little unclear where in the boot process is the pocketbeagle's device tree being "declared"? Where in the boot process does /dev/spidev becomes available? And how can I make it start earlier?

Comment: Spidev is a kludge that provides a userspace interface in place of writing a dedicated SPI protocol driver. Since there is no userspace until the kernel has booted and the init process has begun, what you ask is totally unreasonable. You need to write real drivers for the SPI slave device that you want to access.  Seems like you have an XY problem.

Comment: BTW one convenient way of using an *"ILI9341 display"* in Linux is with the [Linux Framebuffer drivers for small TFT LCD display modules](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki)

Comment: And if you run it with a framebuffer it's as easy as `cat /opt/fancybootscreen > /dev/fbX` to get your shiny pretty much instantly on boot.

Comment: Also note that currently there's a 2s delay between U-Boot and the Kernel: `Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds`. That might be relevant to you.

Comment: @TBR, true... Is there any way to remove that 2s delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing @sawdust and my comments into an answer:

- Don't use SPIdev for this
- Use the [Linux Framebuffer drivers for small TFT LCD display modules](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki)
- Set [`bootdelay` to 0 or -2 in U-Boot Env](https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootEnvVariables)

  - Don't worry about the warning, you can recover and modify the Env file by booting from SD card or if on SD, by modifying its contents on a computer.
- Add a systemd service to render your splash screen early during boot

  - [Simple and has some good pointers](https://www.madebymany.com/stories/fun-with-systemd-running-a-splash-screen-shutting-down-screens-and-an-iot-product-service-with-python-on-raspberry-pi)
  - [Quite verbose, not everything applies (e.g. console), but might contain some good bits to selectively pick out](https://yingtongli.me/blog/2016/12/21/splash.html)